# Can the Cherish Ball be inherited through breeding?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

While breeding pokemon, the child pokemon generally inherits the mother's type of pokeball (excluding the Master Ball). For example, if a mother caught in an Ultra Ball has a child, the child will be in an Ultra Ball as well. But, there is a special type of pokeball known as the Cherish Ball which can be received through events. For example, Manaphy is known as the legendary that can breed and Manaphy has recently been given out through an event in which it came in a Cherish Ball. Can/Will Manaphy's child inherit the Cherish ball?

Comment: I hope you know that Manaphy will breed a Phione, you don't get another Manaphy :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The cherish ball and master ball are exceptions to pokéball inheritance. If you catch a pokémon in either of these balls and breed it, the child will **always** be born in a regular pokéball instead.

Source: [Smogon breeding guide](http://www.smogon.com/ingame/guides/special_ball), [projectpokemon](https://projectpokemon.org/forums/showthread.php?37683-Inheriting-Pok%E9ball-trough-breeding), [serebii's ball legality page](http://www.serebii.net/games/geniball.shtml), [bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9_Ball#Types_of_Pok.C3.A9_Balls), personal experience

Comment: Welp, I had no idea.

Answer (score -1):

I've actually tried this with a Genesect (White 2) and Magearna (Moon). It will always be a regular pokéball instead of a cherish ball. Same with master ball.

Comment: How do you even try this with Pokémon that can't breed?

Comment: Also don't post an answer to repeat what someone else already said